# JQuery autocomplete and images speed issues

Tags: jquery, image, autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete to load products complete with thumbnails.

The trouble is that each image load takes up a http request and most browsers have a limit on how many requests can be made to one hostname in parallel.

What this means is after typing the first letter into search the script will immediately fetch 20 images (for example), but this exceeds the parallel http requests limit which means an immediate subsequent letter press does not carry out the ajax instantly.  Instead it waits in queue until the previous images have loaded.  Only then will the search update.

This is very frustrating for the user, especially considering that the images I'm using are quite large in file size.

The only way I have found to overcome this is to place the javascript on a separate sub domain to the images, then JS loads instantly without waiting for images to load.  However this is not a solution I can use in this project.

Any other solutions?

Comment: For speed, why not generate a sprite that you preload? That way there would be only one image request and the load time would be near instant as the user types.

Comment: Well, the product database contains 4000 products each with 1 to 5 images.  More products are being added on a daily basis, I think generating such a sprite may be too resource intensive.  What are your thoughts?